# Can I record two videos at the same time on android?

Tags: android, video, mediarecorder, video-recording

I'm developing an android application which requires to have 2 video recordings at the same time.

The first MediaRecorder object records with 4k size and second one records with very small size about 300 x 300.

Is that possible? If is not, please let me know another way..

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Resize the new video after the 4k is recorded ?

Comment: No, I mean at the same time.. But if resizing time is taken shortly, it's ok.